# Posting a Message to a running Thread using Handlers

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I have code which calls a new Thread that connects to an IRC server. The thread has loop to listen for response from the IRC server and calls a method 'ProcessData' to action the response.

On my UI I want to be able to 'QUIT' the IRC server in onStop and onPause. The trouble I have is that when I use a Handler to post a message to my IRC thread which sends a QUIT command to the IRC server it tells me that I am performing network operations on the UI thread.

The handler is setup in my IRCManager class (this class extends Thread and is the class I run on a separate thread.

```
public Handler networkHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        try {
            processData((String) msg.obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "network handler given an object NOT of type String");
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }

};
```

I use the handler from the main activity and instantiate it just after starting the network thread

```
irc.start();
networkHandler = irc.networkHandler;
```

In the onPause event I send a message to the handler

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.obj = IRCManager.QUIT;
networkHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

EDIT: Here is the processData method

```
void processData(String data) throws IOException {

    if (data.contains("PING")) {
        String pingId = data.substring(6, data.length());
        sendMessage(pong + pingId + "\n");
        isConnected = true;

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 1;
        msg.obj = "test";
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    } else if (data.contains("Welcome")) {
        sendMessage("PRIVMSG " + BOT_NAME + " JOIN " + siteId + "\n");

    } else if (data.contains(IRCManager.QUIT)) {
        disconnect();

    } else if (isClientConnected()) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 2;
        msg.obj = "test";
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

It seems that the handler isn't linking properly to the thread. Can anyone shed any light on how I can do this?

My thread actually spends 99% of it's time in a while loop checking the inputstream from the IRC server. This may also have something to do with it.

Comment: Can you post the processData method?

Comment: Hi there, I have updated the original post

Comment: Does sendMessage() make network calls?

Comment: Yes. It sends a message to the IRC server

Comment: Then that is your Network operations on the main thread.

Comment: I understand that. But I want it to run on my network thread. That is why I am using a handler. But it isn't working that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the instance of the `Handler`, `networkHandler`, here:

```
public Handler networkHandler = new Handler() {
```

It'll be therefore associated with the UI thread.

And, when you say:

> I use the handler from the main activity and instantiate it just after starting the network thread
>
> ```
> irc.start();
> networkHandler = irc.networkHandler;
> ```

You're not creating the instance of the `Handler` there; you're just grabbing a reference to it.

You actually need to create the instance of the `Handler` in the `run()` method of your non-UI `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another constructor with `new Handler(new Handler.Callback() )` inside